# Как вернуть данные ajax-запросе из php, не выводя ничего в echo?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Сейчас есть ajax-запрос:

```
$(".form").on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".js-copy_button").attr("disabled", true);
        $(".js-copy_info").css("display", "inline-block");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'parser/parser.php',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $(".js-message_block").html(data);
                $(".js-copy_button").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
```

И по итогу выполнения скрипта выводится ссылка в блок `".js-message_block"`

**php:**

```
echo "<a class='button result_button js-result_button' href='landings/" . $landingName . "' target='_blank'>Посмотреть</a>";
```

Можно ли как-то вернуть данные, не выводя ничего через echo, вернуть ссылку, чтобы кнопку сформировать через js?

Comment: Как вы собираетесь отправить ответ с сервера, не используя механизм отправки ответа с сервера? Какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Вам просто нужно поменять `dataType: 'text'` на `dataType: 'json',`, чтобы в ответ от сервера вы получали переменную для js, php должен быть в формате json - `echo json_encode(array('url' => 'http://bla-bla-bla...'));` тогда, при получении вы сможете использовать эту переменную в JS обратившись к ней так: `data.url`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вопрос вообще звучал, "не выводя в echo", а не "без ответа". echo это тело ответа, а оно в целом не обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Выше правильно написали, dataType - формат должен быть только в JSON.

> $(".js-message_block").html(data);

Вот так не надо с JSON-response, никогда. В этом месте вытаскиваете из data объект для JS, и делайте с ним что хотите, формируете кнопку на основе этого объекта.

Comment: success: function(data){
  $(".js-message_block").html(data);
  $(".js-copy_button").attr("disabled", false);
}

Замените вторую строку тут на console.log(data), должен быть ответ от сервера в виде ообъекта;
Остальное тут не надо - то что у вас в success.